Como corregir la advertencia CS8602 al utilizar Contains
Cordial saludo. En la actualidad estamos experimientando en nuestro codigo una advertencia generada cada que utilizado Contains,esta es la advertencia CS8602. Al ser una advertencia, no nos genera errores de compilacion, pero nos gustaria quitar estos errores. Hemos podido notar, que esto se da, cuanto el tipo de dato al que se le aplicará el Contains, es del tipo string? (permite valores null). Suponemos que las variables son inicilizadas en null y por ello el Contains de alguna forma, indica que eso no deberia ser. Hasta el momento, no hemos logrado encontrar la forma de corregir la advertencia. Este es el codigo:
[HttpGet("/Llantas/Salidas/Agregar/Obras", Name = "GetLlantasSalidasAgregarObras")]
    // 2024-03-08: Este metodo es para construir otros, pero como no me interesa que sea visible en el web API,
    // lo pongo como private y no como public.
    private List<TemLlantasSalidasRegistros> GetLlantasSalidasAgregarObras(int Anho, int Mes)
    {
        try
        {
            //2024-01-23: Aqui obtengo el nombre de la obra
            var q = from a in context.LlanSalidasLlantas
                    join b1 in context.GeneAlmacenObra on
                        a.bodega
                    equals
                        b1.Bodega
                    into GrupoB
                    //Esto lo hago para que que sean LEFT JOIN.
                    from b in GrupoB.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where
                        a.fecha.Year == Anho
                        &&
                        (
                            Mes == 0 
                            || 
                            Mes == a.fecha.Month
                        )                       
                        &&
                        a.equipo.Contains("VD") // Suppress CS8602
                    select new TemLlantasSalidasRegistros
                    {
                        Registro = a.Registro,
                        equipo = a.equipo,
                        bodega = a.bodega,
                        nom_bodega = a.nom_bodega,
                        cod_familia = a.cod_familia,
                        familia = a.familia,
                        fecha = a.fecha,
                        codigo = a.codigo,
                        descripcion = a.descripcion,
                        tipo_salida = a.tipo_salida,
                        tipo = a.tipo,
                        numero = a.numero,
                        cantidad = a.cantidad,
                        costo = a.costo,
                        total_costo = a.total_costo,
                        destino = a.destino,
                        horometro = a.horometro,
                        adicional = a.adicional,
                        horometro_ingresado = a.horometro_ingresado,
                        empresa = a.empresa,
                        Obra = b.Obra,
                        //2024-01-24: Esta operación lo definiremos con la ayuda de una función con la cual
                        //identificaremos el tipo de llanta que se esta montando.
                        Operacion = null,
                        //2024-01-24: Este estado lo definiremos en un metodo mas adelante.
                        Estado = null
                    };
            return q.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception) 
        {
            return TemLlantasSalidasRegistrosExcepcion;
        }

    }

Como pudieron notar, la advertencia aparece en esta linea:
a.equipo.Contains("VD") // Suppress CS8602

Alli, se resalta el dato a.equipo.
Para nosotros es muy importante identificar esta novedad y corregirla para eliminar varias advertencias que nos estan saliendo.
Importante menciona que el dato equipo es del siguiente tipo:
public string? equipo { get; set }

Agradecemos su ayuda.

En general es como indica @CarlosMuñoz en su respuesta, debes agregar
a.equipo?.Contains("VD") ?? false

Si a.equipo es null saltará a la derecha y evitará la excepción que daría (porque un null no tiene la función Contains)
Desde hace algunas versiones atrás de Visual Studio que esta advertencia ha sido integrada al IDE para evitar lo que se denomina "El error de los mil millones de dólares", es muy interesante leer de donde viene y todos los problemas que trae consigo, en mi experiencia es lejos el error más común.
Y como te decía anteriormente, si a.equipo es null dará un NullReferenceException, porque null no cuenta con la función Contains, esto siempre es cierto en un IEnumerable
Pero no es así en un IQueryable que obtiene los datos desde una base de datos, por ejemplo, al utilizar Entity Framework ya que en este caso a.equipo.Contains no se ejecuta, sino que se transforma en una sentencia SQL
Por ejemplo, a.equipo.Contains("VD") en SQL Server se transformaría en:
WHERE equipo LIKE N'%VD%'

O en SQLITE haría:
WHERE equipo IS NOT NULL AND instr(equipo , 'VD') > 0

Y si te fijas en ningún caso importa que equipo sea null, por lo que podemos indicarle a Visual Studio que no se preocupe utilizando el operador !
a.equipo!.Contains("VD") 


Muchas gracias Yussef, pregunta, que es lo que hace el operador !

@GermanDavid el operador ! se llama null-forgiving, se usa para suprimir la advertencia de "un posible nulo". En algunos casos la variable es nulleable, pero por la lógica de la aplicación, nosotros como desarrolladores, podemos determinar que es imposible que esto pase en la práctica. Es ahí donde este operador nos permite suprimir la advertencia, tal como el caso de ejemplo que te indico, donde sí LlanSalidasLlantas es un DBSet<T>, la función Contains no se ejecuta, sino que se convierte a una sentencia SQL

Pues efectivamente equipo está definido como string? lo que significa que pude ser null con lo cual la llamada a .Contains lanzaría un NullReferenceException.
Para solucionarlo puedes llamar condicionalmente a Contains si es que no es null mediante el operador ?., en caso de no ser null se comportará igual que antes y en caso de ser null a toda la expresión puedes agregarle ?? false (o true) dependiendo de como es tu lógica. Esto hará que en caso ser null tome el valor de la derecha es decir el false (o true si tiene más sentido).
Esa línea quedaría así:
a.equipo?.Contains("VD") ?? false

